# Using JavaScript to detect window size and outputting a link to a script

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm using a jQuery plugin, however, I would only like to use it when a visitor is using their computer, not their mobile device.

Something along the lines of detecting the "availWidth" and if it's less than 600, output a "" in the .

Is this possible with JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: You probably wanted the `User-Agent` header, not the screen resolution.

Comment: Search for "detecting mobile device", it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/